# How to rename files before upload

Tags: c#, javascript, file-upload, file-io, dropzone.js

I need to rename every file uploaded using `dropzone.js` to add a timestamp in his name.

I already tried to do this in the server side, but I can't recover the modified name and set it into the script to do a deletion on server when file is deleted on the browser.

I tried to rename the file int the script too, before upload, but unsuccessful. The functions I tried to use are these:

```
accept: function (file, done) {
    file.name = "timestampHere" + file.name;
    done();
}
```

And this:

```
sending: function (file, xhr, formData) {
    file.name = "heee" + file.name;
}
```

But in both cases, I can't recover the file name and change it to proceed a file delete on the server when the "Remove" button is fired.

In other words, the file in the server have the time stamp and in browser doesn't.

**There's any way to recover the name of the file saved on the server and set it into the script on the browser *OR* rename the file in the script, before the upload?**

My target here is to delete the file on the server too on click of the "Remove" button, after inserting timestamp in the name of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17457380/2394172

The context is different of mine, but I've used his concept, creating a repository with an array of objects containing the original name and the server name.

With this I can compare the values and send to the server just the server value.

I hope this can help someone.