# Delete script for Dropzone.js and PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone for file upload. I want to delete the files on the server when the `removeLink` is clicked. For that I use Ajax which opens the .php site. But somehow I can't pass the filename of the file which should be deleted (the `delete_image.php` works). How can I pass the filename so it can be deleted?

```
 addRemoveLinks: true,
 removedfile: function(file) {
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'delete_image.php',
data: {name: +file, dir: "<? echo $_GET['id']; ?>"},
});
 var _ref;
 return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) :       void 0;        
  }
```

Credit: [code from this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452662/dropzone-js-how-to-delete-files-from-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most simple way

JS file,this script will run when you click delete button

```
this.on("removedfile", function(file) {
alert(file.name);

$.ajax({
url: "uploads/delete.php",
type: "POST",
data: { 'name': file.name}
});


});
```

php file "delete.php"

```
<?php
$t= $_POST['name'];
echo $t;
unlink($t); 
?>
```