# DropzoneJS remove files using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I am using the [DropzoneJS](https://www.dropzonejs.com) library to upload files. The controler save it directly on the server (inspired by [DropzoneJS with ASP.net MVC 5 Tutorial](http://sampathloku.blogspot.com/2014/02/dropzonejs-with-aspnet-mvc-5.html))

It works but I don't get how to call the controler on the DropzoneJS's event *removedfile*. Here is my code :

**Script :**

```
<script>
    Dropzone.options.dropzone = {
        addRemoveLinks:     true,
        dictDefaultMessage: "Drop here",
        dictRemoveFile:     "Delete"
    }
</script>
```

**csHtml :**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Form", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "dropzone", @class = "dropzone" }))
{
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
}
```

**Controler :**

```
public ActionResult UploadFile()
{
    foreach (string requestFile in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[requestFile];
        // Save on server
    }

    return Json(new { response = "File uploaded." });
}
```

How can I call a new controler like `UploadFile()` to remove my files ?

Answer (score 1):

See DropzoneJS is a ux framework, it only allows the user to interact with their scenario at the moment, you cannot call a method to upload files to delete them.

If you recover the files you uploaded, you must control the deletion with another controller action and search for the file by a id or uid belonging to the image in cuestion, any identifier to remove it from your local.

You may want to look to the second answer in this question.

**since I can't write comments, I'm posting it as an answer.

[Dropzone.js- How to delete files from server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452662/dropzone-js-how-to-delete-files-from-server)[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452662/dropzone-js-how-to-delete-files-from-server)